# Creating new dataset with only the most recent date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, subset

I am trying to create a new table where table1 is grouped by ID and only the most recent date is picked from table1$new.

I have the tables below:

**1st Table:**

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-02-01 |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-02-01 |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-02-21 |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-04-21 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-05-01 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-05-01 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-05-21 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-07-21 |
| 003 | 1004 | 2021-05-01 |
| 003 | 1004 | 2021-05-01 |
| 003 | 1004 | 2021-05-21 |
| 003 | 1004 | 2021-07-21 |

**Current Output**

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-02-01 |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-02-01 |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-02-21 |
| 001 | 1003 | 2021-04-21 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-05-01 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-05-01 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-05-21 |
| 002 | 1003 | 2021-07-21 |

**Desired Output:**

| ID | New |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-4-21 |
| 002 | 2021-07-21 |

**Here is my code as of now**

```
desired <- table1 %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
subset(Status == '1003', select = c("ID", "Date")) %>% rename(New = Date)
```

I think my first mistake is in the group_by and I am not sure how to only keep the most recent date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `dplyr::slice_max()` to select the most recent date.

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Status,        ~Date,
  "001",   1003L, "2021-02-01",
  "001",   1003L, "2021-02-01",
  "001",   1003L, "2021-02-21",
  "001",   1003L, "2021-04-21",
  "002",   1003L, "2021-05-01",
  "002",   1003L, "2021-05-01",
  "002",   1003L, "2021-05-21",
  "002",   1003L, "2021-07-21",
  "003",   1004L, "2021-05-01",
  "003",   1004L, "2021-05-01",
  "003",   1004L, "2021-05-21",
  "003",   1004L, "2021-07-21"
)

res <- d |> 
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) |> 
  dplyr::filter(Status == 1003) |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  slice_max(Date, n = 1) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(ID, New = Date) # rename variable in the selection of variables
res
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   ID    New       
#>   <chr> <date>    
#> 1 001   2021-04-21
#> 2 002   2021-07-21
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there any reason why I couldn't do?: `desired <- table1 %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
subset(Status == '1003', select = c("ID", "Date")) %>% slice_max(Date, n=1) %>% rename(New = Date)`

Comment: I don't really the subset function. But, That works too apparently. You just have to make sure that your Date is really read as a Date, and not as a character.

For tidyverse, you can use `dplyr::filter()`, and `dplyr::select()`

I updated my answer.